# Best way to rotate the 3D image in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, scipy, deep-learning

I have the 3D image with the voxel size of 1mmx1mmx1mm. It is a medical image. I am applying it to deep learning and I need to augment the dataset. I choose the rotation to augment the dataset.

```
from scipy.ndimage import rotate
image_rotate=rotate(img, angle=angle, reshape=False, axes=axes)
```

I found that when I rotate to angle=10, then the result is rotated again to angle=-10, the obtained result is not so same the original image. It means I compute the mean square error (MSE) between them and it is non-zero. Do we have the better way to achieve a small MSE in python?

The full code is

```
from scipy.ndimage import rotate
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
img_original = np.copy(img)
image_rotate_10=rotate(img, angle=10, reshape=False, axes=axes)
image_rotate_neg10=rotate(image_rotate_10, angle=-10, reshape=False, axes=axes)    
mse = mean_squared_error(img_original, image_rotate_neg10)
#Or compute number of different pixel
error = ((label_original - labels) ** 2).sum(axis=None)
```

Comment: This is due to the fact that when rotating an image the old pixels will not end  up at exat pixel positions, due to the limited screen resolution. Thus, all pixel values need to be calculated from a region of pixels in the original image. To some extent this can be seen as a low pass filtering operation (averaging) and as such you will loose information in the process. Therefore, you are not likely to be able to recover the image by an inverse rotation, since that will apply the filtering (information reducing) operation once more.

Comment: Can you share your image?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why would you care that rotating an image forth and back does not result in exactly the same image? Just don't rotate and you should be fine. But if you have to rotate the images in order to align them you may have to [accept that this is a lossy operation](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/41996/is-rotation-an-intrinsic-lossy-operation-for-angles-not-multiple-of-90-degrees). Finally, I'm not an expert on deep learning but can't you design a rotation-invariant network?